# convert date timestamp with month name to mm/dd/yyyy format using excel formula

Tags: excel-formula

**ColumnA** has values `"June 21, 2018 12:00:00 AM EDT"`, `"September 11, 2018 12:00:00 AM EDT", "August 23, 2018 12:00:00 AM EDT"`. Need to convert **ColumnA** values to mm/dd/yyyy format using excel formula. Is that possible?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: when the day of the month is less than 10 is there a leading zero? When the hour is less than 10 is there a leading 0?

Comment: Did you try using Text-to-Columns and make it all the way to the 3rd page on the pop up wizzard?

Comment: The concepts in the linked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37318173/how-to-convert-timestamp-in-text-format-to-actual-date-format-of-ms-excel/37318696#37318696) may help you.  you will need to tweak the references and order of functions but the gist should all be there:

Answer (score 0):

You can either format the cells directly or use a helper column to achieve desired format. You can*not* use a formula if the output is limited to strictly `Column A`.

---

**For formula solution:**
enter the below in `B2` and then drop down

```
B2 = TEXT (A2, "mm/dd/yyyy")
```

**For non-formula solution:**
Highlight `Column A` > Format Cells > Date > Select "mm/dd/yyyy" format option.